# SSL caches javascript file even with dynamic version query string

Tags: javascript, caching, ssl, https

This only happens under `https` but when I make a change to a javascript file, and update the version number like below the original file is still cached on reload.  Im not doing any kind of fancy caching for this, and seems to work fine under http, but https and even iframes dont work well.  I am using asp.net and IIS7, any thoughts on how to make sure this file is updated when I make a change cause it causes problems on the client side browser.

```
http://example.com/example.js?v=485
```

Comment: Reloading the page in the browser should reload the javascript file as well, thus getting the new version.  SSL should not affect this unless there is a browser bug.

Comment: It has and does though.  I have seen it and my clients have.

Comment: That's why I said, "unless there is a browser bug".